# LinkedIn API historical followers call return http status code 500

Tags: javascript, rest, api, express, linkedin-api

I have been searching the entire internet for an solution of this problem, but can't seem to find any answers that solve my problem.

I'm trying to get historical followers from LinkedIns API with this call: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/${companyId}/historical-follow-statistics?time-granularity=day&start-timestamp=${from}&end-timestamp=${to}&format=json
from my Node/Express application.
I've put the headers like this:
Authorization: Bearer 'mytoken' (retrieved from an OAuth2 login).

I keep getting this error code back:

```
{
"errorCode": 0,
"message": "Internal service error",
"requestId": "22BM2KPRXF",
"status": 500,
"timestamp": 1489395675897
}
```

I can easily make calls to other endpoints.

I think i am doing exactly what the docs say: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

So my question is: What am i doing wrong? Is it an error with that exact endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that apparently almost everything other than the "get followers" endpoint doesn't work on the testcompany, but do indeed work on the correct company... LinkedIn please fix this. I've spent hours figuring this out...

Comment: any followup on this? I keep getting 500 for many company endpoints.

Comment: Last time i checked LinkedIn recommended to use stackoverflow to ask questions and to report problems too (I assume). [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support#)

So i guess they read through some of these posts and eventually fix bugs like these when they get enough attention. Or at least tell how to solve the problem if it isn't a bug.

Comment: I was actually receiving 500 because I was making requests on the demo account they provide. It probably has limitations and simply blows up with 500 (M$) ...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP response code 500 (Internal Server Error) should mean that there's an unhandled issue within their service (LinkedIn).

You should be able to safely assume that there is an issue with the endpoint in their service. When issues like this occur I find it useful to approach the developers through any ticket services LinkedIn provides. It's also likely that the issue will be resolved in a few hours / days if the issue is being experienced by a lot of people.

If this was an issue with your code, you should expect an error code starting in 4 such as `401 Unauthorized`, `403 Forbidden`, or `400 Bad Request`. All of this assumes it conforms to general REST/HTTP standards which I believe LinkedIn do.